# Problems with modal view launched over a split view controller

Tags: ios-simulator, uisplitviewcontroller

I have created a split view application that begins with a modal view splash page. The problem is that the modal view always launches in portrait mode, even if  the ipad is in landscape. If I rotate the ipad a couple of times, it rotates appropriately. I have set UIInterfaceOrientation in my Info.plist, but it doesn't have any impace.

in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, I am using the following code

```
...
[self.window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
SplashViewController *modalView = [[SplashViewController alloc] intiWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
modalView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[splitViewController presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
...
```

Any suggestions on how I can ensure the modal view launches in landscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the better way to do it:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));

Comment: To add a bit of information, I _had_ to subclass UIViewController and override **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation**, then present that as the modal view controller from my split view controller.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using [Matt Gemmell's MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController). In my case, by trying to open a modal view controller in FormSheet mode from inside the detail view controller (that is the "right" pane in the UISplitViewController standard), my modal view was forcing interface rotation to portrait.
I found the solution by overriding the modal view controller -> shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: and letting him returning a NO:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return NO;
}
```

In this way when the modal is going to be presented, for some reason the OS tries to force it to portrait. By answering NO the view is no more rotated and everything works fine.

Comment: You can't actually return NO as the answer because you'll get a runtime warning whining about no orientations being supported and it will default to portrait. Your answer helped me figure it out though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the file from which you launch the modal view, you will want to change/override the following function. You can simply copy and paste the following code and you should be able to launch the modal view in <s>portrait</s> landscape mode:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Good luck.

**EDIT:** I said portrait mode instead of what I meant: landscape mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am launching the modal view from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. The method above has already been set in the .m files for the view controllers that appear within the split view and in the modal view controller itself. All to no avail