# iOS - show modal popover view controller over splitviewcontroller at startup

Tags: ios, ipad, modal-dialog, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm working on an iPad app which requires a login screen.  I'd like the login screen to appear as a modal popover in the centre of the screen, over the top of the underlying screen which is controlled by a UISplitViewController.  Ideally I'd like the 'master' view to be hidden and then appear after a successful login.  I understand my UISplitViewController has to be the root controller, so I need to launch the popover from either the master or detail view at an appropriate event.  I'm a bit stuck as to where this should happen, and whether the UIPopoverController should be a property of the master or detail views.

Any help greatly appreciated,

Jonathan

Comment: How do you want to trigger the display of the popover? Through a button?

Comment: The popover should display automatically when the app launches for the first time, but should also be able to display on the touch of a button (when the user clicks 'Logout').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some leads for what you are trying to achieve:

**Show / Hide master view:**
By default the master view is visible in portrait mode. As mentioned in the [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISplitViewControllerDelegate/splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:) you can alter this behavior starting ios5. You can play with this method to achieve the display or not of the master view for any orientation.

```
 - (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc  inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
```

**Display a modal popover in the center of the screen**
Your modal popover view needs to be presented from the SplitViewController when the application is launched. I have seen in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750813/problems-with-modal-view-launched-over-a-split-view-controller) a possible way to do this in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`You shouldn't launch the popover from either the master or the detail controller.